# TalkBack screenreader accessibility not working on non-clickable image view in android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement talkback for image view in android.

But TalkBack screenreader accessibility not working on non-clickable image view in android

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If I add `android:clickable=true` and `android:focusable=true`, it will be announced for accessibility but this not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You must add

> android:contentDescription

in your XML or

> setContentDescription()

programmatically in your code.

Comment: I have added setContentDescription() programatically. do I need to add any click event for image? as this image is only informative image.

Comment: @kittu it shouldn't be needed